# PyGTK: How do I make a custom widget look like a gtk.Notebook tab?

Tags: python, coding-style, tabs, pygtk

I'm writing a program and I need some extra functionality from the gtk.Notebook widget, so I have taken to creating my own.

My only problem is styling my tabs so that they look like the tabs in gtk.Notebook and will change according to the user's theme.

I really don't know where to start so any advice would be much appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: `notebook` tag removed as part of the [2012 cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem eventually by getting the colours from gtk.Notebook's style.

Comment: Please always show the code that was used, so others can learn and/or adapt from it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, if you are going to create something similar to a gtk.Notebook, I'll recomment you to subclass gtk.Notebook to save a lot of work.